# Get session data in a generic handler mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generic-handler

While I am trying to retrieve session value from a generic handler, it throws "object reference not set to an object. Here is my code-

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
          Int32 UserId=Convert.ToInt32(context.Session["UserId"]);
    }
```

}

How to solve this issue?

Thank you.

### UPDATE

This link solved my issue
[ASP.NET Generic Handlers & Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889437/asp-net-generic-handlers-session)

Comment: Try `context.Current.Session["UserId"]`.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` will give you the ongoing request.