# How can I pass parameter to generic handler being called in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using jquery autocomplete and I am getting data from a generic handler that makes a call to database.

**Java Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#managerNo').autocomplete({
            source: 'ManagerHandler1.ashx'
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Generic Handler: (ManagerHandler1.ashx)**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
        List<string> listManagerNames = new List<string>();

        string myConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ArtistManagementSystem"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnection))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetManagerNames",conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@term",
                Value = term
            });
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                listManagerNames.Add(dr["Cell"].ToString());
            }
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listManagerNames));

    }
```

Actually I am trying to load numbers using autocomplete and that is working just fine. What I want to do is, Load numbers `where ID = someid`.

I am getting UserID from Session on Page_Load() function.

**Page_Load()**

```
if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            USERid = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        }
```

I have changed the stored procedure for that and its also working fine.

**StoredProcedure:**

```
CREATE proc spGetManagerNames 
@term varchar(50) = NULL,
@UsrID bigint 
as
Begin
    Select Cell
    from Manager
    where Cell like @term + '%' and [User ID]=@UsrID
End
```

Now since I am getting the `User ID` from Session, so I want to pass that to the handler, how can I do that? Kindly help me out.

Comment: `since I am getting the User ID from Session` - where are you doing this, it's not evident from your code - there's no reference to `context.Session["UserID"]` in the code whatsoever

Comment: OK, so you have `USERid` - just add that to the cmd.Parameters just like you did for the `term` parameter ... wait, does an `.ashx` page even have a `Page_Load()` method?

Comment: No it doesn't have a Page_Load(). How am I supposed to get the Session value in my Generic Handler class?

Comment: so use `context.Session["UserID"]` in `ProcessRequest` like I already suggested - what confused me was the statement that you were getting the userid, I assumed you meant in the handler - so, you actually are not getting the userid in the handler - which is the opposite

Comment: You need to implement the `IRequiresSessionState` interface to access session variables in a Generic Handler. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889437/asp-net-generic-handlers-session

Comment: Oh yeah, that too

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working now.